# Textarea past one after one on click

Tags: javascript, textarea

I need to do the following:

1. Copy one column with some values to textarea.
2. Textarea copies one line at a time after click on button
3. Pastes the copied value into the second textarea, one line after the other, without overwriting (not the whole one, only one by one)

Here is my testing code:

```html
<textarea id="txt1" rows="10" cols="100" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
<textarea id="txt" rows="4" cols="50" onclick="eraseText()"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="displayOut()" value="click">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function eraseText() {
    document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
  }

  function displayOut() {
    var input = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    var text2 = document.getElementById("txt1");
    text2.value = input;
    if (input.length === 0) {
      alert("Please enter a valid input");
      return;
    }
    eraseText();

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 1. "need help!" in the title will make people avoid looking into this post. Please fix the grammar of the title. 2. What does the enumeration mean? Is the enumeration the steps to reproduce the problem or instead the desired behavior? Write down what exactly the problem is and what should happen instead. 3. Make more effort correcting the grammar and write whole sentences (I’m unable to understand it). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your question was a bit unclear but gave it a try anyway.

```js
function eraseText() {
  document.getElementById("txt").value = "";
}

function displayOut() {
  var input = document.getElementById("txt").value.trim().split('\n').map((line) => line.substr(0, 1)).join('\n');
  var text2 = document.getElementById("txt1");
  text2.value = text2.value.length ? [ text2.value, input ].join('\n') : input;
  if (input.length === 0) {
    alert("Please enter a valid input");
    return;
  }
  eraseText();
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txt1" rows="10" cols="100" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
<textarea id="txt" rows="4" cols="50" onclick="eraseText()"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="displayOut()" value="click">
```

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Script should output the data in that way:
for example:
Input data: 
tes1
test2
test3
on click output :
(first click)test1 (second click)-> test2(third click) test3

Comment: Late reply, so every click a new column gets added to the output `div` or does it replace the entire output value with the current column?